# Instance variables in ruby utility module that extends self?

Tags: ruby, module, instance-variables

I'm making a utility module that have some simple functions - I want the module to extend self so it does not need to be instantiated. A coworker and I were discussing various ways to store data in these types of modules, and one example he provided was this, using an instance variable:

```
module ExampleModule
  extend self

  @my_instance_variable = "Hello from module"

  def do_thing
    puts "**** #{@my_instance_variable}"
    @my_instance_variable
  end
end
```

This isn't an approach we decided to use, but I wanted to get a better understanding of why it works / best alternatives. So, a few questions:

Why does this work? How can a module method called without an instance access instance variables? Could you point me to any ruby docs / articles discussing this behavior?

Thoughts on if / when this is an appropriate pattern? (i'm not a fan since it seems counterintuitive for a module like this to have instance variables)

Should a class variable be used here instead? Our [rubocop flags @@foo class variables as a code smell](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: `@@`-style class variables are trouble, they can behave in surprising ways, which is why they're flagged by default. I'd avoid these if you can.

Comment: You may want to define this as `def self.do_thing` instead of adding `extend self`, which does imply this can be used as a mixin as well.

Comment: Modules can have instance variables as they themselves are instances of Module. 

Comment: I suggest you remove the Rails tag as this is a pure-Ruby question.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby modules can have instance variables. This goes for classes as well as they are a kind of module. If you use the `Module.new` method instead of the keyword this becomes even more apparent:

```
module Foo
  @bar = "Hello World"
  def self.bar
    @bar
  end
end

# is pretty much equivilent to
Foo = Module.new do
  @bar = "Hello World"
  def self.bar
    @bar
  end
end
```

The only real difference between the example above and your code is that you're using `extend self` - which causes `do_thing` to be callable on the module and not just classes which include the module.

I'm not a huge fan of this and IMHO it would be better to just define the methods explicitly with `def self.method_name` which is clearer about intent and can be picked up by static analysis.

> Thoughts on if / when this is an appropriate pattern? (i'm not a fan since it seems counterintuitive for a module like this to have instance variables)

One very common use for module instance variables is [the configuration pattern](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/mygem-configure-block):

```
module MyGem
  class << self
    attr_accessor :configuration
  end

  def self.configure
    self.configuration ||= Configuration.new
    yield(configuration)
  end

  class Configuration
    attr_accessor :mailer_sender

    def initialize
      @mailer_sender = 'donotreply@example.com'
    end
  end
end
```

Here a set of gem specific settings are stored in `@configuration`. You then set this in a initializer file which is loaded when booting the app:

```
MyGem.configure do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = 'donotreply@example.com'
end
```

This allows app wide settings without relying on globals.

Module/class instance variables can be confusing if you're new to Ruby but remember that in Ruby everything is an object and that instance variables are not defined properties of a class. They are just variables which are lexically scoped *to an instance of something* which can be a module, class or an instance of a class.

> Should a class variable be used here instead? Our rubocop flags @@foo class variables as a code smell

Class variables in Ruby have a lot of unexpected behaviors and for that reason are usually best avoided. For example they are [shared between a class and all of it's subclasses](https://rubystyle.guide/#no-class-vars).